# UDP buffer in C# on XP

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, udp

I have a continuous stream of udp packets to a computer running windows xp.
At some point I start a listener (written in C#) that handles the udp packets received.

When I start the listener, will I get packets that were sent before the listener was started due to a buffer, or can I be certain that the first packet I get into my listener is actually the first packet received since the listener was started?

Answer (score 4):

UDP delivery is not guaranteed to arrive in order, to arrive at all, to arrive only once, or **to arrive after a certain time**.

Therefore, you'll need to also handle UDP packets that have been sent *before* you started listening to the port, but for some reason took a world tour and did not arrive until *after* you started listening.

In most O/S implementations, when a UDP packet arrives to a port (and it is not broadcast) and there is no one listening on UDP on that port, the packet gets discarded.  However, there is a chance that a UDP packet arrives at the O/S and gets queued in the network driver's internal buffer, *before* the O/S has a chance to process it when your listener starts.  Then you'll also see it.

In general, never assume anything reliable to come from UDP packets.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is there a way to flush out the buffer at O/S level?

Comment: Not when it only arrived at the network card's device driver.  Is there any particular reason why you need something so deterministic, yet choose to go with UDP?  You are probably using the wrong tools for the task.

Comment: It's a commercial product continuously streaming UDP packets. I have no choice on the matter, and I have to somehow estimate what packets are received when.

Comment: You shouldn't really be trying to sync UDP packets, as the delivery is not guaranteed to be in order, nor does it guarantee to arrive fast or slow.  The fact the the packet arrives after you started your listener doesn't say anything about when the packet was sent from its source.  I suggest that you simply start the listener and take any packet from then on.

Comment: It is data from a scientific instrument. (Don't ask why UDP was chosen). The stream is usually rather stable (as there is a direct link from the instrument to the computer), so that the UDP uncertainties arising from multiple network routers is minimize. My worry is _when_ the packet is actually received, is there then some internal buffers within the O/S and .NET framework that exposes previously received packets to my listener.

Comment: Not that I know.  Your UDP stream should have some sync marker packets in it, or the the instrument's protocol designer is a very sh*tty programmer...  Not only did he/she choose an *unreliable* transport for *scientific* data, but he/she did not provide a way to detect when/where the stream starts/ends.